# Can exercises help relax your muscles?

Tags: exercise, relaxation

I have heard that there are eye relaxation exercises, and some other muscle relaxation exercises, however exercising requires the  use of energy, how is this possible?

Links:

- [A Workout for Your Eyes](https://www.zeiss.com/vision-care/int/better-vision/health-prevention/a-workout-for-your-eyes-.html)
- [How do I Practice Progressive Muscle Relaxation](https://www.verywellmind.com/how-do-i-practice-progressive-muscle-relaxation-3024400)
- [Eye Relaxation Exercises](https://www.improve-vision-naturally.com/eye-exercises-online/eye-relaxation-exercises.html)
- [How to do Muscle RElaxation Exercises](https://www.verywellhealth.com/how-to-do-muscle-relaxation-exercises-1945349)

Comment: The universal way to relax your muscles is to take few deep breaths, but can you elaborate more ?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: I haven't clicked on any of the links you provided, but the URL's of them imply that they're mostly to do with eye health? If that's what you're curious about, you might want to edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Yoga has many eye relaxation exercises. You can do it with ease. No energy is required for that and proves relaxing if you work with computers, then it will be very helpful. And if you have weak eyesight then it will prove very much helpful in long run if you do it daily.

Here I would like to share link from which you can practice these exercises.
https://www.artofliving.org/in-en/yoga/health-and-wellness/yoga-eyes
[Eye exercise][1]

Stay healthy
Thank you,

Comment: Thank you,but basically an eye relaxation exercise is an exercise,in order to perform the exercise your eye muscles have to contract,how can this help relax our eyes?

Comment: Yes but this exercises provides relaxation to your eyes, which are also mentioned in the links you have provided. Such as palming, focus shifts, looking at distant objects if you work with computers for a longer time. And this kind of exercise don't require any extra energy so eventually you will feel better. I guess you can try few times.

Answer (score 1):

> muscle relaxation exercises, however exercising requires the use of energy, how is this possible?

Exercise does not mean, that all muscles are tense all the time.

There are many muscles in the body and during exercise they work, ie. contract *and relax*, in a certain pattern. For example, when you flex one muscle, the muscle on the other side (ie. the antagonist) automatically relaxes through [reciprocal inhibition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_inhibition). Another mechanism exercise can help to relax is the [inverse myotatic reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golgi_tendon_reflex) where basically the muscle relaxes more after being stretched and tensed. Exercise also benefits circulation in the area.

So think of exercise as bringing balance through a pattern of tension and relaxation. When the body (eg. the eyes) are strained in a monotonous way throughout the whole day, you don't only need to "relax", but you also need to use the muscles in all the different complex ways that are neglected.